# Many for in one line in python generator

Tags: python, list, for-loop, generator

I can't understand code with multi "for"s in one generator like this, I searched Google and didn't find any answer:

```
print [j for i in [[1,2],[4,6]] for j in i ]
# will print [1, 2, 4, 6]

print [j for j in i for i in [[1,2],[4,6]] ]
# will print [4, 4, 6, 6]
```

What is the difference?

How to interpret code like this?

Comment: Works just like a nested for loop

Comment: @MadPhysicist which one is outer loop?

Comment: I am not sure about py2. But in py3, second statement throws me an error

Comment: @Marcus.Aureliannus no errors in 2nd statement

Comment: For py2, both no error @Marcus.Aurelianus

Comment: The second one _does_ error if you haven't already defined `i`. In Python 2, the first comprehension sets `i`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hopefully the expansions will help you reason with the code. It's a lot more readable this way, in my opinion. I'm printing one element at a time instead of the whole list.

```
print [j for i in [[1, 2], [4, 6]] for j in i]
```

is equivalent to

```
for i in [[1, 2], [4, 6]]:
    for j in i:
        print j
```

As a result `i = [4, 6]`.

Now,

```
print [j for j in i for i in [[1,2],[4,6]]]
```

is equivalent to

```
for j in i: # Remember, i = [4, 6]
    for i in [[1, 2], [4, 6]]:
        print j
```

Comment: That last part doesn't quite make sense. Why is the expansion allowed to be backwards in Py2?

Comment: @MadPhysicist The variable `i` leaked out of the first list comprehension, so it was already defined for the second. It's not doing what it looks like it does.

Comment: Oooh. I hadn't noticed that. Very well seen.

Answer (score 2):

first list comprehension is read as

```
mat = [[1,2],[4,6]]
a = []
for i in mat:
    for j in i:
        a.append(j)
print(a)
```

second list comprehension is read as

```
b = []
for j in i:
    for i in mat:
        b.append(j)
print(b)
```

Comment: For second code,  will the "i" in third line affect the "i" in second line?

Comment: Please fix your formatting. Python is whitespace sensitive.

Comment: In the second list comprehension, i = [4,6] and the possible values of j are 4, 6. Since the matrix [[1,2], [4,6]] has 2 rows, while iterating [1,2] the value 4 is appended and while iterating over [4,6] the value 6 is appended to the array b

Answer (score 2):

The second generater is error, but in your code scripts, the second generator, the `i`  will be  `[4, 6]` after your run the first generator, so the second will output `[4, 4, 6, 6]`

Answer (score 1):

Comprehensions can be interpreted as a shorthand for loops whose only statement is to append an element to the list they create. The syntax you show is how nested loops are implemented.

For example, your first snippet `[j for i in [[1,2],[4,6]] for j in i]` can be rewritten as

```
result = []
for i in [[1,2],[4,6]]:
    for j in i:
        result.append(j)
```

Note that the order of the loops in the comprehension is the same as in the expanded form.

Your second snippet `[j for j in i for i in [[1,2],[4,6]]`  then becomes

```
result = []
for j in i:
    for i in [[1,2],[4,6]]:
        result.append(j)
```

As you can see, this will simply fail with a `NameError` at the start of the first loop since `i` is not defined at that point.